# how to find the total number of car tickts each year, using pyspark?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I ran a few SQL quires, to find the number of tickets per year.
but i receive an analysis error

error :

```
AnalysisException Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-81-7a082d111e8c> in <module>
      1 # Total number of tickets for each year
----> 2 sql_ticket_year = spark.sql("select year(Issue_Date) as year, count(Summons_Number) as no_of_tickets from Ptable group by year order by desc")
      3 sql_ticket_year.show(50)
      4 sql_ticket_year.count()
      5 # error while counting the ticket number
```

Code segment :

```
# creating a local temporary view of the table, to apply some Quires 
parking.createOrReplaceTempView("Ptable")
spark.sql('Select * from Ptable') 
# Total number of tickets for each year
sql_ticket_year = spark.sql("select year(Issue_Date) as year, count(Summons_Number) as no_of_tickets from Ptable group by year order by year")
sql_ticket_year.show(50)
sql_ticket_year.count()
# error while counting the ticket number
```

[image]

Comment: `group by year(Issue_Date)` not for `year` that is just an alias yet.

Comment: could you clarify you answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Your query is wrong.

```
sql_ticket_year = spark.sql("""
    select year(Issue_Date) as year
         , count(Summons_Number) as no_of_tickets
      from Ptable
     group by year(Issue_Date)  <---
     order by year(Issue_Date)  <---
""")
```